# Ways to identify that proteins are regulating different genes experimentally

Tags: homework, cancer, experimental-design, gene-regulation

As part of my study I have been given this hypothesis:

> HIF 1a and HIF 2a regulate different genes in multiple myeloma

What ways do we have to identify that these proteins are regulating different genes in multiple myeloma? I recall in lectures something being mentioned about using antibodies to isolate the regulatory elements, but can't find any specifics.

Any help is seriously appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

[Chromatin immunoprecipitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatin_immunoprecipitation) (ChIP) or [ChIP-Seq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ChIP-sequencing) are the first methods that pop into my mind. Essentially, DNA is cross-linked to bound proteins (transcription factors, histones, etc.) by various methods, then broken into pieces by either [sonication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonication) or digestion with micrococcal nuclease. An immunoprecipitation is then performed by adding antibodies targeting your protein of interest (HIF-1α and HIF-2α in this case), allowing them to bind to their targets, enriching them using bead-conjugated Protein G (or Protein A), then reversing the cross-linking. The enriched DNA can then either be subjected to PCR for known genes (ChIP), or it can be sequenced and aligned with a reference genome to determine all bound sequences (ChIP-Seq).